# biblatex-apa puts comma at the end of collection-entries instead of period

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, apa-style

I am writing my thesis with biblatex-apa style for biblatex. Unfortunately biblatex-apa behaves strange for whole collections. Instead of putting a period at the end of such an entry it puts a comma there.

This minimum example shows what I mean:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{collection.bib}
@COLLECTION{Doe2013,
  editor = {Doe, John},
  title = {Some collection},
  year = {2013},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  location = {Location}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,autopunct=true]{csquotes}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\bibliography{collection}

\begin{document}
Some text and then a cite \parencite{Doe2013}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It produces this:

[http://web263.login-1.hoststar.at/johanngruendl/files/example.jpg http://web263.login-1.hoststar.at/johanngruendl/files/example.jpg](http://web263.login-1.hoststar.at/johanngruendl/files/example.jpg)

Since I was about to finish my thesis when I found this problem, I would be very grateful if someone could provide a quick fix for this strange behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in version 5.9 is seems. Quick fix:

change line 1386 of `apa.bbx` from

```
\printtext{\printfield{number}}%
```

to

```
\printfield{number}%
```

Don't know why that `\printtext` was in there. Will be taken out in next version.

Comment: Thank you very much!

It is line 1390 in version 5.7 (which is the version one will currently have with TeX Live 2012).